# How to disable discrete zoom level in android google maps?

Tags: android

Android google maps sdk approximate zoom level to discrete values. I mean that i cannot set it to 13.33 it will convert it to 13. However Google Android Maps application doesn't do it. How they achieved that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible, because Google Maps Application uses vector maps api not available for developers.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `MapView.getController().zoomToSpan(LatSpan,LonSpan)`.